# visa for uk as a family member of EEA National

Tags: visas, uk

My question is that can i go to uk without any visa for a holiday with my husband and children under 18.all of them are european national.only i have an indian  passport but having a 10 year permanent card in spain as a  family member of eea natinal mentioned in my card.

Comment: What's the down vote for?

Comment: In case it's not clear from the linked question, you should be able to travel to the UK without a visa.